# Splitting an excel 2010 spreadsheet into multiple workbook files based on column value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I find and clean a lot of contact data, sorted by country, which I am currently using excel to manage. Mainly because it is easier to clean and manipulate the data I find this way, and I can easily share each country's data with my colleagues. Currently there are multiple workbooks organised by country (as we have about 280,000 contacts in total and having them in one workbook is unwieldy).

So the folder structure is

```
Argentina
Australia
Austria
etc...
```

Each containing a spreadsheet called

countryname.xlsx

I have another 'dashboard' spreadsheet reporting the totals from each individual workbook along with contact segmentation totals.

The format for the workbook is something along the lines of

Australia.xls

```
Country          Department      Name            Email               Telephone          
Australia        Finance         John Doe        test@test1.com      07..
Australia        Admin           Jane Doe        test@test2.com      07..
Australia        Sales           Bill Pond       test@test3.com      07..
etc...
```

There are about 28 column descriptors.

What I would like to happen is have one workbook, say:

Workinprogress.xlsx

And as I add data to this, it be automatically added to each country's workbook once saved, preserving all the columns. I can then wipe it and start fresh each day knowing the the data is being stored by country.

Is there any functionality that can do this automatically in Excel 2010, or will this require VBA (as I suspect it will)?

Comment: It will require a lot of VBA. Seems like if you are going to invest the time to do this, it may be better to convert the whole thing to a Database. Easier to grow (or stay large with >280k records already) and easier to maintain and send reports from.

Comment: I agree, even an Access database would be better than excel for something of this nature.

Comment: Echoing the other's comments. You are describing the built in functionality of Access with a form on top of it. At the very least, a hybrid solution where your directory structure and workbooks are database tables and your workinprogress.xlsx has some VBA to update the tables. You may struggle with implementing that solution if you lack DB experience, but the VBA necessary to pull of what you want with the directory structure will be the bane of your existence. The bane of your existence.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but as a reference:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const Q         As String = "'"
Private Const ROOT      As String = "E:\Test\"
Private Const FLDR      As String = "SubFolder"
Private Const DASHBRD   As String = "Db.xlsx"

Public Sub updateAllFiles()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, sql As String
    Dim fs As Variant, updateVals As String, rng As Range, allFiles As Long, i As Long
    Dim fld As Variant, cName As String

    fs = fileListFSO    'fileListXL
    allFiles = UBound(fs)
    If allFiles > -1 Then
        Set ws = Worksheets(1)
        Set rng = ws.UsedRange.Rows(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count)

        rng.Replace Q, """" 'remove single quotes (')
        updateVals = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rng)), Q & "," & Q)
        updateVals = Replace(Replace(updateVals, "[", vbNullString), "]", vbNullString)
        updateVals = Q & updateVals & Q
        Set cn = New ADODB.Connection: Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

        For i = 0 To allFiles
            cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & fs(i) & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0"";"

            sql = "Select * From [Sheet1$]"
            rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText: rs.Close

            sql = "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] Values " & "(" & updateVals & ")"
            rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText: cn.Close
        Next
        Set rs = Nothing: Set cn = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

.

These functions return a 1-dimensional array with fully qualified file names (full path)

```
Private Function fileListFSO(Optional ByVal fldrPath As String = ROOT & FLDR) As Variant
    Dim fso As Variant, FLDR As Variant, f As Variant, result As Variant
    If Len(Dir(fldrPath, vbDirectory)) > 0 Then
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set FLDR = fso.GetFolder(fldrPath)
        For Each f In FLDR.Files
            If InStr(f.Name, "~$") = 0 And InStr(f.Name, ".xlsm") = 0 Then
                result = result & f.Path & ","
            End If
        Next
        fileListFSO = Split(Left(result, Len(result) - 1), ",")
    End If
End Function



Private Function fileListXL(Optional ByVal xlFile As String = ROOT & DASHBRD) As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, result As Variant
    If Len(Dir(xlFile)) > 0 Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xlFile, ReadOnly:=True)
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
        result = Join(Application.Transpose(ws.UsedRange.Columns(1)), ",")  'col to str
        fileListXL = Split(result, ",")                                     'str to arr
        wb.Close
    End If
End Function
```

.

Updating file:

[image: update Closed WB 1]

Test Files:

[image: update Closed WB 4 - Files]

Test Files - Before:

[image: update Closed WB 2 - Before]

Test Files - After:

[image: update Closed WB 3 - After]

.

Notes:

- All files to be updated should be in the same folder
- All files (including the updater) should have exactly the same format (same number of columns)
- All updated files (including the updater) should have the data on the first sheet, named "Sheet1"
- All updated files should have the data formatted as Text (for the ADO Insert statement)
- DashBoard file (db.xlsx) should have a list of all files in column A, on a sheet named "Sheet1"

  - All files should include the full path

Comment: It's always nice to see SQL in VBA. But I haven't understood your example yet. Where does the user select at which destination XLS the record should go? Something like the *country name* or in your example *Book1*. Oh, and a +1 is the minimum for your effort

Comment: Thanks @nixda - I did it as an exercise and focused on how to do the batch updates. The code  provides 2 ways of getting the list of files to be updated, one with FSO (using ROOT and FLDR), and the other by reading the list from the dashboard file "Sheet1", column A (including the full paths). It can be updated to use a dialog box for the source folder and dashboard file, and recursively update all sub-folders as well. Currently it assumes that all files have a "Sheet1" (hard-coded) and will read and update the last record in all of them.